# Looping JSON in WebAPI Controller and Add new Property

Tags: c#, performance, json, json.net

I have a json array that is being passed into a function.  Whenever the function comes across a field (call it Field1) in a record with a value that starts with "@!!!@" the function compile them into a list to fire off to another server. I have code that looks like this in the initial function:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    dynamic request = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();

    JObject data = (JObject)request;
    var directive = data["Directive"];

    var json = data.Last.First;

    string url = null;

    if (directive.ToString() == "D")
    {
        url = "registry/get";
    }
    else if (directive.ToString() == "S")
    {
        url = "registry/sanitize";
    }



    JArray payloadArray = (JArray)json;

    string newToken = null;

    List<JObject> objList = new List<JObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= payloadArray.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        string newJson = null;
        foreach (var prop in payloadArray[i])
        {
            newJson = newJson + prop.ToString() + ",";
            if (prop.ToString().Contains("@!!!@"))
            {
                JObject newProp = new JObject();
                newProp.Add(prop);
                newJson = newJson + "\"" + newProp.Properties().First().Name + "\":\"sanitize|" + prop.First + "\"," + "\"@" + newProp.Properties().First().Name.ToString() + "\":\"" + prop.First + "\",";
                // newJson = newJson + "\"@" + newProp.Properties().First().Name.ToString() + "\":\"sanitize|" + prop.First + "\",";
                newToken = newToken + "{\"Token\":\"" + prop.First + "\",\"ProcessId\":\"" + prop.First.ToString().Replace("@!!!@", "") + "\"},";
            }
        }
        objList.Add(JObject.Parse("{" + newJson + "}"));

    }

    string outGoingPayload = "{\"Registry\":[" + newToken + "]}";

      var content = new StringContent(outGoingPayload.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

       HttpResponseMessage response = MakeRequest(outGoingPayload.ToString());


 var responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject responseJson = JObject.Parse(responseBodyAsText.Result);
int counter = 0;
foreach(JObject item in objList)
{
    foreach(var itm in item)
    {
        if (itm.Value.ToString().Contains("sanitize|@!!!@"))
        {
            foreach(var resItem in responseJson)
            {
                if (resItem.Value[counter]["ProcessId"].ToString() == itm.Value.ToString().Replace("sanitize|@!!!@",""))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        itm.Value.Replace(resItem.Value[counter]["Value"].ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        itm.Value.Replace("Token not found");
                    }     
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

string jsonStr = null;
foreach (var val in objList)
{
    jsonStr = jsonStr + val + ",";
}

jsonStr = "[" + jsonStr.TrimEnd(',') + "]";
var returnArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);


    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "returnArray");
}
```

For a Json payload of 1000 records this take 5000ms to run.  What can I do to improve performance here?  Setup of the system is the payload passed into the function will contain all records, I must build up a new payload to pass into the remote service to get corresponding values.  I do this as one HttpClient request.  So this means I loop the initial payload, build up the new payload, call the remove service, return all matches and loop the initial payload and add the extra field where appropriate.  I am trying to get this function to return a bit faster.  I have tried using Linq to JSON I have tried treating the json as a string.  The code I have posted seems to be the fastest.  I can provide more information if needed.

Sample payload to send to this function:

```
{
"Directive":"S",
"Wrapper":[
{
 "Field1":"Apple",
 "Field2":"Peach",
 "Field3":"@!!!@008d613d1ca60885468bf274daa693cc778430fc8a539bdf2e7dc2dec88cd922",
 "Field4":"Kiwi"
},
{
 "Field1":"Apple2",
 "Field2":"Peach2",
 "Field3":"@!!!@17e9ad37968e25893e96855ba3d633e250a401a6584b2bc9c7288f9fc458a9b6",
 "Field4":"Kiwi2"
}]}
```

Sample to send the intermediate function (I cannot touch this one but it's already optimized) My function should build this from the above payload:

```
{ "Wrapper":[
{"Token":"@!!!@17e9ad37968e25893e96855ba3d633e250a401a6584b2bc9c7288f9fc458a9b6"},
{"Token":"@!!!@008d613d1ca60885468bf274daa693cc778430fc8a539bdf2e7dc2dec88cd922"}
]}
```

Return from intermediate service:

```
{ "Wrapper":[
{"Token":"@!!!@17e9ad37968e25893e96855ba3d633e250a401a6584b2bc9c7288f9fc458a9b6", "Value":"test"},
{"Token":"@!!!@008d613d1ca60885468bf274daa693cc778430fc8a539bdf2e7dc2dec88cd922", "Value":"test2"}
]}
```

Back in my function both the original payload and the return payload from the intermediate function should be merged and returned like this:

```
  {
    "Wrapper":[
       {
         "Field1":"Apple",
         "Field2":"Peach",
 "Field3":"@!!!@008d613d1ca60885468bf274daa693cc778430fc8a539bdf2e7dc2dec88cd922",
  "@Field3":"test2",
  "Field4":"Kiwi"
     },
{
 "Field1":"Apple2",
 "Field2":"Peach2",
 "Field3":"@!!!@17e9ad37968e25893e96855ba3d633e250a401a6584b2bc9c7288f9fc458a9b6 ",


"@Field3":"test"
           "Field4":"Kiwi2"
           }]}
```

Comment: Please post the complete method, not a _random_ snippet. If possible the class.

Comment: sure give me a moment and I will do that.... just FYI the bottleneck is in the first function the remote service called cannot be modified and is already optimized.  Let me upload the entire class.

Comment: Was only able to put the function in not the whole class.  The only other method in the class is the call to the remote service.

Comment: This looks much better now ;-) I think the whole class isn't necessary here. The method provides enough context.

Comment: Could you also add a sample of the json you are transforming to have something to play with? A sample result would be also very helpful :-]

Comment: I just saw this.  I will post some sample json and result tomorrow morning.   Thanks.

Comment: In the first line of the method, why read as `dynamic` when you are casting it to `JObject` in the next line? Can you replace those 2 lines with `JObject.Parse(await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())`?

Comment: This function is an azure function... this was the template they start you off with.  I sure can try that.  Let me also upload some sample json.  Working on that now, just have to sanitize it.

Comment: @FurkanKambay - I was able to change those lines and for readability they should stay like that but it didn't decrease the latency between the call and response.

Comment: @t3chb0t - I was able to add the payload/response example JSON... Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I'm not happy about you not posting the entire code the first time but I'm glad you've decided to do it after all ;-)

Comment: I had to make sure it was sanitized and ok to do so  :).  I was unable to post the intermediate service (the optimized one) that returns the values to my function.  Thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: I've fully updated the functions/payloads - hopefully that helps.

Comment: Have you identified what is slow? How long does it take `MakeRequest()` to return?

Comment: @MattCole - MakeRequest takes about 1.5 millisecond per record to return which is right on target.  Seems the initial loop through the json to build the payload FOR MakeRequest is taking some time as well as after MakeRequest returns and we loop it's payload and merge it with the initial JSON that is taking some time.  Seems the bottle neck is in the code I've posted.

Comment: So if your 1000 items each have on average 3 tokenized fields that is 1000*3*1.5 = 4500ms for your intermediate call? Seems it would be the bottleneck if this is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are what in my opinion are the primary areas of concern.

*Misuse of Json.NET*

Code like `JObject.Parse("{" + newJson + "}")` is redundant. You are manually forming a JSON string and then deserialising it back into a JObject. You can just [build JTokens directly](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm), avoiding the cost of deserialization and having to mess around with formatting.

*Inefficient Token Replacement*

After the service call, you update the original items very inefficiently. Lets say you have 1000 items each with 3 tokenised fields. That would be 3000 results from your service call. Your code iterates through all 3000 results for each of the 3000 tokens, resulting in a total of ~9000000 iterations. I’ll show you below how to reduce this to just 3000.

**A Possible Solution**

If you create some classes to deserialize to/from, the code will be much easier to work with, removing the need to deal with `JTokens` at all. To fix your 9 million iterations problem, you could use a dictionary to create a lookup table when you initially loop over the properties. The key could be the token, and the value could be a reference to the item that needs to be updated. Then once you have your token values, you just need to iterate over them, updating the dictionary (fast). I've put a console app together [here](https://gist.github.com/mattwcole/f0db8dc307988e39571aacb29c42ec73) that works with your example JSON to demonstrate. The key parts are as follows.

*Form service request and lookup table*

```
foreach (var item in inputData.Wrapper)
{
    foreach (var kvp in item.Where(property => property.Value.StartsWith("@!!!@")))
    {
        propertiesLookup[kvp.Value] = new ItemUpdate
        {
            Properties = item,
            UpdateKey = kvp.Key
        };
        propertiesRequest.Wrapper.Add(new PropertySearch
        {
            Token = kvp.Value
        });
    }
}
```

*Use lookup table to add tokenized fields to items*

```
foreach (var item in intermediateData.Wrapper)
{
    var itemToUpdate = propertiesLookup[item.Token];
    itemToUpdate.Properties[$"@{itemToUpdate.UpdateKey}"] = item.Value;
}
```

Comment: It would be much cooler if you included the example code in your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions and help on this.  I am going to take a look at this attachment now.